# Why can't I call a constructor outside an initial or always block?

Tags: system-verilog

I tried to run this code using Synopsys VCS:

```
class parent;
int a = 10;
endclass

class child extends parent;
int b = 10;
endclass

module main;
  parent P;
  child C;

  P = new();
  C = new();

  initial begin
    $display("a=%d\n",C.a);
  end
endmodule
```

It is giving an error at the object creation after the handle declaration. The error is as follows:

> Error-[SE] Syntax error Following verilog source has syntax error : "class.sv", 20: token is '=' P = new();

However, when I change the module "main" to this

```
module main;
  parent P = new();
  child C = new();

  initial begin
    $display("a=%d\n",C.a);
  end
endmodule
```

I get no such error. Why is this?

Answer (score 2):

The error is caused by the fact that these two lines:

```
P = new();
C = new();
```

are *procedural code* - they must be inside an `initial` or `always` block. They are procedural code, because they call a function - the *constructor* "new".

These two lines, however, are *declarative code*:

```
parent P = new();
child C = new();
```

and so they are legal outside an `initial` or `always` block. They are declarative code because they declare two objects (`P` of class `parent` and `C` of class `child`). These objects are also *initialised* by calling their constructors. These two objects have *module scope* - they will be visible throughout the module.

It is also legal to put these two lines of code inside an `initial` or `always` block (as long as they appear before any procedural code). In that case, the two objects will have *block scope* - they will only be visible inside that block.